# timechart is crating stats which are not part of the search in splunk

Tags: splunk

I was extracting some volume data for PE testing from prod systems, using following query

I am expecting to get stats from 9AM to 6PM event counts with respect to proxy names. but following code creating stats for entire day please help me to remove these extra data.

Query

```
index= index_Name environmentName= Env_name clientAppName="App_Name"
| eval eventHour=strftime(_time,"%H")
| where eventHour<18 AND eventHour>=9
| timechart count span=60m by proxyName
```

result :

| TIme | Proxy1 | proxy2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-16 06:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-02-16 07:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-02-16 08:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-02-16 09:00 | 27 | 34 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to narrow the time window is by using the `earliest` and `latest` options in the search command.

To find the events between 9am and 6pm today:

```
index= index_Name environmentName= Env_name clientAppName="App_Name" earliest=@d+9h latest=@d+18h
| timechart count span=60m by proxyName
```

To find the events from yesterday between 9am and 6pm:

```
index= index_Name environmentName= Env_name clientAppName="App_Name" earliest=-1d@d+9h latest=-1d@d+18h
| timechart count span=60m by proxyName
```

The `@d+9h` construct says to go to the beginning of the day and add 9 hours.